# Get path above basepath, node js

Tags: node.js

To get the base path of the node js app, you can use `process.cwd()`.

```
opt/myapp/backend //process.cwd() points here

opt/myapp // How do I get this path?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require('path').normalize(path+'/..);
```

should get you what you want.